# Global.asax for php

Tags: php, global-asax

I've been a .Net developer and a Java developer and TBH I liked .Net more when it comes to web (Except that I had to use IIS). Recently I've learned php (Amazingly simple) but I was wondering if in php you could do something like the Global.asax in .Net. I'm just looking for someway to mimic the Application_Error event.

Comment: What does `Application_Error` do?

Comment: Eventhough you mention asp.net this question has nothing to do with it. You should consider removing that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following are closest to what you want:

- [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)
- [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)